# Fraction (rational number) structure with custom operators

Tags: swift, rational-numbers

First, the struct itself:

```
struct Fraction {
    var numerator: Int
    var denominator: Int {
    didSet (oldDenominator) {
        if self.denominator == 0 {
            self.denominator = oldDenominator
        }
    }
    }

    init() {
        self.init(numerator: 0, denominator: 1)
    }

    init(numerator: Int) {
        self.init(numerator: numerator, denominator: 1)
    }

    init(reciprocalOf denominator: Int) {
        self.init(numerator: 1, denominator: denominator)
    }

    init(numerator: Int, denominator: Int) {
        self.numerator = numerator;
        self.denominator = denominator;
    }

    mutating func reduce() {
        let gcd = greatestCommonDenominator(self.numerator,self.denominator)
        self.numerator /= gcd
        self.denominator /= gcd
    }

    func fraction() -> (numerator:Int,denominator:Int) {
        return (self.numerator,self.denominator)
    }
}
```

The GCD function the struct's `reduce()` function uses:

```
func greatestCommonDenominator(first: Int, second: Int) -> Int {
    return second == 0 ? first : greatestCommonDenominator(second, first % second)
}
```

An extension on `Int` to conveniently make some of these fractions:

```
extension Int {
    var fraction: Fraction {
        return Fraction(numerator: self)
    }
    var reciprocalOf: Fraction {
        return Fraction(reciprocalOf: self)
    }
}
```

And now for the operators.  First, your basic add, subtract, multiply, and divide:

```
@infix func + (first: Fraction, second: Fraction) -> Fraction {
    let numerator = (first.numerator * second.denominator) + (first.denominator * second.numerator)
    let denominator = (first.denominator * second.denominator)
    var frac = Fraction(numerator: numerator, denominator: denominator)
    frac.reduce()
    return frac
}

@infix func - (first: Fraction, second: Fraction) -> Fraction {
    let subtractor = Fraction(numerator: -second.numerator, denominator: second.denominator)
    return first + subtractor
}

@infix func * (first: Fraction, second: Fraction) -> Fraction {
    let numerator = first.numerator * second.numerator
    let denominator = first.denominator * second.denominator
    var frac = Fraction(numerator: numerator, denominator: denominator)
    frac.reduce()
    return frac
}

@infix func / (first: Fraction, second: Fraction) -> Fraction {
    let divisor = Fraction(numerator: second.denominator, denominator: second.numerator)
    return first * second
}
```

I don't think the modulo operator makes sense here, given we're dealing with fractions.  Is there an operator I'm missing?

Now, the compound assignment operators:

```
@assignment func += (inout left: Fraction, right: Fraction) {
    left = left + right
}

@assignment func -= (inout left: Fraction, right: Fraction) {
    left = left - right
}

@assignment func *= (inout left: Fraction, right: Fraction) {
    left = left * right
}

@assignment func /= (inout left: Fraction, right: Fraction) {
    left = left / right
}
```

I actually don't know if these are strictly necessary, or if Swift will allow these and assume `left = left + right` to be `left += right` and overloading is only necessary if you need something custom.  I'm not sure.

I also wrote functions for doing math with a fraction and an integer:

```
@infix func + (fraction: Fraction, integer: Int) -> Fraction {
    return fraction + integer.fraction
}

@infix func - (fraction: Fraction, integer: Int) -> Fraction {
    return fraction - integer.fraction
}

@infix func * (fraction: Fraction, integer: Int) -> Fraction {
    return fraction * integer.fraction
}

@infix func / (fraction: Fraction, integer: Int) -> Fraction {
    return fraction / integer.fraction
}

@infix func + (integer: Int, fraction: Fraction) -> Fraction {
    return integer.fraction + fraction
}

@infix func - (integer: Int, fraction: Fraction) -> Fraction {
    return integer.fraction + fraction
}

@infix func * (integer: Int, fraction: Fraction) -> Fraction {
    return integer.fraction * fraction
}

@infix func / (integer: Int, fraction: Fraction) -> Fraction {
    return integer.fraction / fraction
}
```

What can be improved?  What's missing?

Comment: I would explore having your `init` function return an optional `Fraction`, with a `nil` value when the denominator is `0`. `Fraction(numerator:1, denominator:0)` should NOT just silently return a `Fraction` object that is invalid and will cause trouble later.  Swift's optionals seem tailor-made to handle this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most of your code looks nice to me, too. Here are some remarks:

- Your definition of / is wrong. It should use the divisor.
- Maybe make the creation of Fractions more lightweight by using `init(_ numerator: Int, _ denominator: Int)` so that you could write `Fration(3,4)`?
- By your definition by didSet it is possible to have `Fraction(1,0)` which might not be intended.

Personally, I would make Fraction an immutable structure. Then you could test for 0 on creation like this

```
init?(_ numerator: Int, _ denominator: Int) {
    if denominator == 0 { return nil }
    ...
}
```

and also reduce on creation.

And one more thing, how about this addition?

```
extension Fraction : IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    init(integerLiteral value: IntegerLiteralType) {
        self.init(numerator:value)
    }
}
```

With it you can simply write `12` instead of `12.fraction`.

Answer (score 3):

I think everything looks quite nice here.  It runs well, and you run the necessary checks to make sure that everything is safe.

I did notice that you went to great extent to implement a bunch of operators for your `Fraction` structure.  But you forgot to implement the common prefix and postfix operators.  Say I want to do this to your structure:

```
var test = Fraction(numerator: 3, denominator: 5)
test++
```

The Swift Playground environment will throw this error at me:

> ```
> Playground execution failed: error: <EXPR>:137:1: error: 'Fraction' is not identical to 'Float'
> test++
> ```

You can combine the `@assignment` attribute with either the `@prefix` or `@postfix` attribute, as in this implementation of the postfix increment operator (`++a`) for `Fraction` instances:

```
@postfix @assignment func ++ (inout frac: Fraction) -> Fraction {
    frac += 1.fraction
    return frac
}
```

Now the Playground environment doesn't complain at me for using my much-loved common operator.  I'll leave it up to you to implement the rest of them (since they aren't too hard to implement `;)`).

Comment: Yeah.  Those definitely ought to be added.