# Formattable Fraction

Tags: c#, formatting, rational-numbers

I have written this small little program, to test how my `Fraction` type behaves when used with and without a custom `FractionFormatter` - I've implemented two custom formatters:

- `FractionFormatter`, which simply puts the numerator at the left of a slash, and the denominator at the right (`"{0}/{1}", fraction.Numerator, fraction.Denominator`),
- `MathJaxFractionFormatter`, pushes the customization a bit further by formatting the fraction as *MathJax*, so `2/5` could be rendered as `\$\frac{2}{5}\$` which produces \$\frac{2}{5}\$ in CR posts.

> ```
> static void Main(string[] args)
> {
>     var fraction1 = new Fraction(2);
>     var fraction2 = new Fraction(2, 4);
>
>     Console.WriteLine("Fraction1: {0} (decimal: {1})", fraction1, fraction1.ToDecimal());
>     Console.WriteLine("Fraction2: {0} (decimal: {1})", fraction2, fraction2.ToDecimal());
>
>     Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2} (decimal: {3})", fraction1, fraction2, fraction1 + fraction2, (fraction1 + fraction2).ToDecimal());
>     Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2} (decimal: {3})", fraction1, fraction2, fraction1 - fraction2, (fraction1 - fraction2).ToDecimal());
>     Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2} (decimal: {3})", fraction1, fraction2, fraction1 * fraction2, (fraction1 * fraction2).ToDecimal());
>     Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2} (decimal: {3})", fraction1, fraction2, fraction1 / fraction2, (fraction1 / fraction2).ToDecimal());
>
>     var jaxFormatter = new MathJaxFractionFormatter();
>     var fraction3 = new Fraction(2, jaxFormatter);
>     var fraction4 = new Fraction(2, 4, jaxFormatter);
>
>     Console.WriteLine("Fraction3: {0} ({1})", fraction3, fraction3.ToString(null, new FractionFormatter()));
>     Console.WriteLine("Fraction4: {0} ({1})", fraction4, fraction4.ToString(null, new FractionFormatter()));
>
>     var crJaxFormatter = new MathJaxFractionFormatter("\\$", MathJaxFractionFormatter.MathJaxFractionSize.Large);
>     var fraction5 = new Fraction(2, crJaxFormatter);
>     var fraction6 = new Fraction(2, 4, crJaxFormatter);
>
>     Console.WriteLine("Fraction5: {0}", fraction5);
>     Console.WriteLine("Fraction6: {0}", fraction6);
>
>     Console.ReadLine();
> }
> ```

The sandbox program above outputs this:

> ```
> Fraction1: 2/1 (decimal: 2)
> Fraction2: 2/4 (decimal: 0.5)
> 2/1 + 2/4 = 5/2 (decimal: 2.5)
> 2/1 - 2/4 = 3/2 (decimal: 1.5)
> 2/1 * 2/4 = 1/1 (decimal: 1)
> 2/1 / 2/4 = 4/1 (decimal: 4)
> Fraction3: $\frac{2}{1}$ (2/1)
> Fraction4: $\frac{2}{4}$ (2/4)
> Fraction5: \$\dfrac{2}{1}\$
> Fraction6: \$\dfrac{2}{4}\$
> ```

---

The `Fraction` type was largely inspired (ok, *stolen*) from [this Objective-C question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/56883/23788) - my implementation is an immutable `struct` though:

```
[Serializable]
public struct Fraction : IFormattable,
                         IComparable, 
                         IComparable<Fraction>,
                         IEquatable<Fraction>
{
    private readonly IFormatProvider _formatProvider;
    private readonly int _numerator;
    private readonly int _denominator;

    public Fraction(int numerator) 
        : this(numerator, 1) 
    {
    }

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
        : this(numerator, denominator, null)
    {
    }

    public Fraction(int numerator, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        : this(numerator, 1, formatProvider)
    {
    }

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        _numerator = numerator;
        _denominator = denominator;

        _formatProvider = formatProvider ?? new FractionFormatter();
    }

    public int Numerator { get { return _numerator; } }
    public int Denominator { get { return _denominator; } }

    public Fraction Simplify()
    {
        var greatestCommonDenominator = GetGreatestCommonDenominator(_numerator, _denominator);

        var numerator = _numerator / greatestCommonDenominator;
        var denominator = _denominator / greatestCommonDenominator;

        return new Fraction(numerator, denominator);
    }

    public decimal ToDecimal()
    {
        return (decimal)_numerator / (decimal)_denominator;
    }

    private int GetGreatestCommonDenominator(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        return denominator == 0 ? numerator 
                           : GetGreatestCommonDenominator(denominator, numerator % denominator);
    }

    public static explicit operator decimal (Fraction fraction)
    {
        return fraction.ToDecimal();
    }

    public static Fraction operator +(Fraction fraction, int integer)
    {
        return fraction + new Fraction(integer);
    }

    public static Fraction operator +(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
    {
        int numerator = (fraction1.Numerator * fraction2.Denominator) + (fraction1.Denominator * fraction2.Numerator);
        int denominator = (fraction1.Denominator * fraction2.Denominator);

        var result = new Fraction(numerator, denominator).Simplify();
        return result;
    }

    public static Fraction operator -(Fraction fraction, int integer)
    {
        return fraction - new Fraction(integer);
    }

    public static Fraction operator -(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
    {
        var subtrator = new Fraction(fraction2.Numerator*-1, fraction2.Denominator);
        return fraction1 + subtrator;
    }

    public static Fraction operator /(Fraction fraction, int integer)
    {
        return fraction / new Fraction(integer);
    }

    public static Fraction operator /(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
    {
        var divisor = new Fraction(fraction2.Denominator, fraction2.Numerator);
        return fraction1 * divisor;
    }

    public static Fraction operator *(Fraction fraction, int integer)
    {
        return fraction * new Fraction(integer);
    }

    public static Fraction operator *(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
    {
        var numerator = fraction1.Numerator * fraction2.Numerator;
        var denominator = fraction1.Denominator * fraction2.Denominator;

        var result = new Fraction(numerator, denominator).Simplify();
        return result;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ToDecimal().Equals((decimal)obj);
    } 

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ToDecimal().GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(null, _formatProvider);
    }


    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (formatProvider is ICustomFormatter)
        {
            return ((ICustomFormatter)formatProvider).Format(format, this, formatProvider);
        }
        else
        {
            return ToString();
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is int)
        {
            return CompareTo(new Fraction((int)obj, 1));
        }
        else if (obj is string)
        {
            int intValue;
            if (int.TryParse(obj as string, out intValue))
            {
                return CompareTo(new Fraction(intValue));
            }
        }

        // will throw an InvalidCastException when obj cannot be cast to a Fraction:
        return CompareTo((Fraction)obj);
    }

    public int CompareTo(Fraction other)
    {
        return ToDecimal().CompareTo(other.ToDecimal());
    }

    public bool Equals(Fraction other)
    {
        return ToDecimal().Equals(other.ToDecimal());
    }
}
```

The `FractionFormatter`:

```
public class FractionFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    private static readonly CultureInfo _culture = typeof(FractionFormatter).Assembly.GetName().CultureInfo;

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        return (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter)) ? this : null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        var fraction = (Fraction)arg;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
        {
            return string.Format(_culture, "{0}/{1}", fraction.Numerator, fraction.Denominator);
        }
        else
        {
            return fraction.ToString(format, _culture);
        }
    }
}
```

And the `MathJaxFractionFormatter`:

```
public class MathJaxFractionFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public enum MathJaxFractionSize
    {
        Normal,
        Large
    }

    private static readonly CultureInfo _culture = typeof(FractionFormatter).Assembly.GetName().CultureInfo;

    private readonly string _delimiter;
    private readonly MathJaxFractionSize _size;

    public MathJaxFractionFormatter()
        : this("$", MathJaxFractionSize.Normal) { }

    public MathJaxFractionFormatter(string delimiter, MathJaxFractionSize size)
    {
        _delimiter = delimiter;
        _size = size;
    }

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        return (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter)) ? this : null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        var fraction = (Fraction)arg;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
        {
            var keyword = _size == MathJaxFractionSize.Normal ? "\\frac" : "\\dfrac";
            return string.Format(_culture, "{2}{3}{{{0}}}{{{1}}}{2}", fraction.Numerator, fraction.Denominator, _delimiter, keyword);
        }
        else
        {
            return fraction.ToString(format, _culture);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you handle 0 denominators?  I'm not familiar with C# and didn't see anywhere that this was handled.

Comment: I... somehow let that slip... ..it'll throw a `DivideByZeroException` whenever `ToDecimal` gets called, ...which means `GetHashCode` can't run for such an instance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Immutable structs

Yay! ✓✓✓

### Format provider

It seems odd to see a format provider in a constructor, and stranger still to store a format provider for every fraction instance. Think of the memory overhead -- imagine a use case where I perform calculations on millions of fractions, but only want to print the end result.

### Whoops

This will not terminate:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Fraction(1, 1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

### Edge cases

<s>As @nhgrif hinted at, you should throw an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception in the constructor for a zero denominator.</s>

As @nhgrif mentioned, you need to be careful handling zero denominators. For example,

```
Console.WriteLine(new Fraction(1) / new Fraction(1, 0));
```

> ```
> 0/1
> ```

### Recursion

`GetGreatestCommonDenominator` can be written iteratively, instead of recursively.

### Culture

Why are you getting the `CultureInfo` from the assembly? I'm not sure, but I think it would be better to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

### API

Add a `ToString(IFormatProvider)` method so you don't have to call it with a first argument of null.

You might also consider providing `MaxValue`, `MinValue`, `Zero`, and `One` fields.

### Comparing fractions

Though I can't say it's *wrong*, it does feel weird to use floating-point values to compare fractions:

```
public int CompareTo(Fraction other)
{
    return ToDecimal().CompareTo(other.ToDecimal());
}
```

I would expect something like this:

```
public int CompareTo(Fraction other)
{
    // TODO: handle case where this and/or other have zero denominator.
    long lhs = _numerator * other._denominator;
    long rhs = other._numerator * _denominator;
    return lhs.CompareTo(rhs);
}
```

Then,

```
public bool Equals(Fraction other)
{
    return ToDecimal().Equals(other.ToDecimal());
}
```

could be

```
public bool Equals(Fraction other)
{
    return this.CompareTo(other) == 0;
}
```

### Nit-picking

Finally, though it's a matter of preference, I would remove the redundant `else`s, e.g.

```
if (obj is int)
{
    return CompareTo(new Fraction((int)obj, 1));
}
else if (obj is string)
{
...
```

Comment: Good catch on `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` - looks like this is where not writing unit tests is biting me! I don't agree with throwing an exception in the constructor for a zero-denominator. Reason is because it's a `struct`, not a `class` - one could always do `var fraction = new Fraction();` and I'd expect `ToString()` to return `"0/0"` for that value. I have already modified this code quite a lot, thanks for your answer! I'll post a follow-up question soon-ish, stay tuned!

Comment: Good point about `var fraction = new Fraction();`, and I don't know the best solution. Maybe `ToString` should return `Undefined` for a denominator of 0.

Comment: In my new code I have a `public bool IsUndefined { get { return _denominator == default(int); } }` property, and `public static readonly Fraction Empty = new Fraction(default(int));`. I like your `CompareTo` implementations a lot, in my new code I've changed `decimal` for `float` and use `float.NaN` when `IsUndefined` is true, using "native C#" comparisons for handling the non-number without throwing.