# Yet Another Fraction

Tags: object-oriented, parsing, vba, rational-numbers

A [recent question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/62552/23788) inspired me to implement a `Fraction` class. I decided to write this one in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), because I like writing tools for <s>the poor souls that still have to deal with that language</s> myself.

I really wanted to be able to create a `Fraction` instance with a static-like syntax, so I created a `FractionType` class with a `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute value of `True` - so I can write code like this:

> ```
> Public Sub Test()
>
>     Dim result As Fraction
>     If FractionType.TryParse("34/178", result) Then
>
>         Debug.Print result.ToString & " = " & result.ToDouble
>
>     End If
>
>     Set result = FractionType.Create(0, 0)
>     Debug.Print result.ToString & " = default? " & result.Equals(FractionType.Default)
>
> End Sub
> ```

...well, if I wanted to output this:

> ```
> 17/39 = 0.435897435897436
> 0/0 = default? True
> ```

---

Because I have a `List` class that can work with objects that implement `IEquatable` and `IComparable` interfaces in my toolkit, I can also use it like this:

> ```
> Dim fractions As New List
> fractions.Add FractionType.Create(1,2), _
>               FractionType.Create(2,3), _
>               FractionType.Create(0,0), _
>               FractionType.Create(9,8), _
>               FractionType.Create(123,345), _
>               FractionType.Create(48,0), _
>               FractionType.Create(12,182)
>
> fractions.Sort
>
> Dim item As Fraction
> For Each item in fractions
>     Debug.Print item.ToString, item.ToSingle
> Next
> ```

As it turns out, I'm especially interested in the `CompareTo` implementation. I decided to split the functionality in two types:

---

> **FractionType** class module

```
Private Const MinimumInt As Integer = -32768
Private Const MaximumInt As Integer = 32767
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Default() As Fraction
    Static result As New Fraction
    Set Default = result
End Property

Public Property Get Zero() As Fraction
    Static result As New Fraction
    result.Numerator = 0
    result.Denominator = 1
    Set Zero = result
End Property

Public Property Get One() As Fraction
    Static result As New Fraction
    result.Numerator = 1
    result.Denominator = 1
    Set One = result
End Property

Public Property Get MinValue() As Fraction
    Static result As New Fraction
    result.Numerator = MinimumInt
    result.Denominator = 1
    Set MinValue = result
End Property

Public Property Get MaxValue() As Fraction
    Static result As New Fraction
    result.Numerator = MaximumInt
    result.Denominator = 1
    Set MaxValue = result
End Property

Public Function Create(ByVal numeratorValue As Integer, ByVal denominatorValue As Integer) As Fraction
    Dim result As New Fraction
    result.Numerator = numeratorValue
    result.Denominator = denominatorValue
    Set Create = result.Simplify
End Function

Public Function Parse(ByVal value As String) As Fraction

    Dim operatorIndex As Integer
    operatorIndex = InStr(1, value, "/")

    If operatorIndex <= 1 _
    Or operatorIndex = Len(value) _
    Then
        RaiseInvalidFormatError value, "Parse"
    End If

    Dim numeratorPart As String
    numeratorPart = Left(value, operatorIndex - 1)

    Dim denominatorPart As String
    denominatorPart = Right(value, operatorIndex - 1)

    Set Parse = Create(CInt(numeratorPart), CInt(denominatorPart))

End Function

Public Function TryParse(ByVal value As String, ByRef outResult As Fraction) As Boolean
On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim result As Boolean

    Set outResult = Parse(value)
    result = True

CleanExit:
    TryParse = result
    Exit Function

CleanFail:
    result = False
    Resume CleanExit

End Function

Private Sub RaiseInvalidFormatError(ByVal errorValue As String, ByVal errorSource As String)
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 44, errorSource, "Error: Invalid format. Value '" & errorValue & "' could not be parsed to a valid fraction."
End Sub

Public Function Simplify(ByVal value As Fraction) As Fraction

    If value.IsUndefined Then
        Set Simplify = value
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim gcd As Integer
    gcd = GetGreatestCommonDivisor(value.Numerator, value.Denominator)

    Dim result As New Fraction
    result.Numerator = value.Numerator / gcd
    result.Denominator = value.Denominator / gcd

    Set Simplify = result

End Function

Private Function GetGreatestCommonDivisor(ByVal value1 As Integer, ByVal value2 As Integer) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer
    If value2 = 0 Then
        result = value1
    Else
        result = GetGreatestCommonDivisor(value2, value1 Mod value2)
    End If
    GetGreatestCommonDivisor = result
End Function
```

---

> **Fraction** class module

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TFraction
    Numerator As Integer
    Denominator As Integer
End Type

Private this As TFraction
Implements IEquatable
Implements IComparable

Public Property Get Numerator() As Integer
    Numerator = this.Numerator
End Property

Public Property Let Numerator(ByVal value As Integer)
    this.Numerator = value
End Property

Public Property Get Denominator() As Integer
    Denominator = this.Denominator
End Property

Public Property Let Denominator(ByVal value As Integer)
    this.Denominator = value
End Property

Public Property Get IsUndefined() As Boolean
    IsUndefined = this.Denominator = 0
End Property

Public Property Get IsNaN() As Boolean
    IsNaN = this.Denominator = 0 And this.Numerator = 0
End Property

Public Property Get IsPositiveInfinity() As Boolean
    IsPositiveInfinity = IsUndefined And this.Numerator > 0
End Property

Public Property Get IsNegativeInfinity() As Boolean
    IsNegativeInfinity = IsUndefined And this.Numerator < 0
End Property

Public Function Simplify() As Fraction
    Set Simplify = FractionType.Simplify(Me)
End Function

Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = this.Numerator & "/" & this.Denominator
End Function

Public Function ToSingle() As Single
    ToSingle = CSng(this.Numerator / this.Denominator)
End Function

Public Function ToDouble() As Double
    ToDouble = CDbl(this.Numerator / this.Denominator)
End Function

Public Function Equals(ByVal other As Fraction) As Boolean

    Dim simplifiedOther As Fraction
    Set simplifiedOther = other.Simplify

    Dim simplifiedMe As Fraction
    Set simplifiedMe = Me.Simplify

    Equals = simplifiedOther.Numerator = simplifiedMe.Numerator _
         And simplifiedOther.Denominator = simplifiedMe.Denominator

End Function

Private Function IEquatable_Equals(ByVal other As Variant) As Boolean
    IEquatable_Equals = Equals(other)
End Function

Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As Fraction) As Integer

    If Me.IsUndefined Or other.IsUndefined Then
        CompareTo = 0

        If Me.IsNaN And other.IsPositiveInfinity Then
            CompareTo = 1

        ElseIf Me.IsNaN And other.IsNegativeInfinity Then
            CompareTo = -1

        ElseIf other.IsNaN Then

            If Me.IsPositiveInfinity Then
                CompareTo = -1

            ElseIf Me.IsNegativeInfinity Then
                CompareTo = 1

            End If

        End If

    Else

        Dim otherValue As Double
        otherValue = other.ToDouble

        Dim myValue As Double
        myValue = Me.ToDouble

        If otherValue > myValue Then
            CompareTo = 1

        ElseIf otherValue < myValue Then
            CompareTo = -1

        Else
            CompareTo = 0

        End If

    End If


End Function


Private Function IComparable_CompareTo(ByVal other As Variant) As Integer
    IComparable_CompareTo = CompareTo(other)
End Function
```

I find the `CompareTo` method sticks out like a sore thumb. Is it just me? How would I write this more elegantly?

Any issues I'm not seeing?

Comment: Are you using `VBPredeclaredId = True` on both classes, or just the Type class?

Comment: @RubberDuck just on the `FractionType` class :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's talk about what I consider to be a bug in the fraction class. Running this code results in an Overflow error.

> ```
> Public Sub bug()
>     Dim item As Fraction
>     Set item = FractionType.Create(0, 0)
>     Debug.Print item.ToDouble
> End Sub
> ```

So let's look at what's going on in the `ToDouble()` function.

> ```
> Public Function ToDouble() As Double
>     ToDouble = CDbl(this.Numerator / this.Denominator)
> End Function
> ```

Okay, so we're diving zero by zero. It's no wonder why we're getting a runtime error. Also note that `ToSingle` suffers from this same issue. The least we can do is raise an error that sufficiently describes what actually went wrong, but I would carefully consider how you really want to handle this issue. It might make for a better API to just return zero, but raising this error is [semantically correct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero).  It's really a judgement call, but ***don't*** make the dev using your class dig into the code to figure out why their getting an overflow error.

```
Public Function ToDouble() As Double
    If IsUndefined Then
        RaiseUndefinedError
    Else
        ToDouble = CDbl(this.Numerator / this.Denominator)
    End If
End Function

Private Sub RaiseUndefinedError()
' Raises Division by Zero Error instead of letting an overflow error happen.
    Const DivByZeroError As Integer = 11
    Err.Raise DivByZeroError, TypeName(Me), "Division by Zero is Undefined"
End Sub
```

---

While your `Fraction.CompareTo` function does not break my Single Screen Principle, I do see an opportunity to clarify it by breaking it down into a few distinct functions. Keep in mind that VB6's `And` operator does not short-circuit. This means that when checking to see if `Me` is not a number, the code will evaluate both calls every time. So, first, a quick refactor to resolve the slight inefficiency.

```
Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As Fraction) As Integer

    If Me.IsUndefined Or other.IsUndefined Then
        CompareTo = 0

        If Me.IsNaN Then
            If other.IsPositiveInfinity Then
                CompareTo = 1
            ElseIf other.IsNegativeInfinity Then
                CompareTo = -1
            End If
        ElseIf other.IsNaN Then
            If Me.IsPositiveInfinity Then
                CompareTo = -1
            ElseIf Me.IsNegativeInfinity Then
                CompareTo = 1
            End If
        End If
    Else

        Dim otherValue As Double
        otherValue = other.ToDouble

        Dim myValue As Double
        myValue = Me.ToDouble

        If otherValue > myValue Then
            CompareTo = 1

        ElseIf otherValue < myValue Then
            CompareTo = -1

        Else
            CompareTo = 0

        End If

    End If

End Function
```

But now we're verging on arrow code. There are two main parts to the `CompareTo` implementation, comparing *undefined* fractions and comparing *defined* fractions. Those sound like pretty good private function names to me.

```
Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As Fraction) As Integer

    If Me.IsUndefined Or other.IsUndefined Then
        CompareTo = CompareUndefined(other)
    Else
        CompareTo = CompareDefined(other)
    End If

End Function


Private Function CompareUndefined(ByVal other As Fraction) As Integer
    CompareUndefined = 0

    If Me.IsNaN Then
        If other.IsPositiveInfinity Then
            CompareUndefined = 1
        ElseIf other.IsNegativeInfinity Then
            CompareUndefined = -1
        End If
    ElseIf other.IsNaN Then
        If Me.IsPositiveInfinity Then
            CompareUndefined = -1
        ElseIf Me.IsNegativeInfinity Then
            CompareUndefined = 1
        End If
    End If

End Function

Private Function CompareDefined(ByVal other As Fraction) As Integer
    Dim otherValue As Double
    otherValue = other.ToDouble

    Dim myValue As Double
    myValue = Me.ToDouble

    If otherValue > myValue Then
        CompareDefined = 1

    ElseIf otherValue < myValue Then
        CompareDefined = -1

    Else
        CompareDefined = 0

    End If
End Function
```

Now, you could repeat this process for `CompareDefined`, but it's not nested *so* badly now, and the function is pretty short and concise as is. You know what though, I'm not quite happy with it... I think this is a case for `Iff()`. It's shorter and undoes the nesting, but does sacrifice a little bit of "understandability" (as any ternary operator would).

```
Private Function CompareUndefined(ByVal other As Fraction) As Integer
    CompareUndefined = 0

    If Me.IsNaN Then
        CompareUndefined = IIf(other.IsPositiveInfinity, 1, -1)
    ElseIf other.IsNaN Then
        CompareUndefined = Iff(Me.IsPositiveInfinity, -1, 1)
    End If

End Function
```

---

There's not much else to say. You generally write very readable code, so I won't bother with any nitpicks about style.

Comment: Consider using `WorksheetFunction.Gcd()`. Why re-invent the wheel? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25745028/380384

Comment: @ja72 that would create a dependency on the Excel library, as it stands, I could import these classes into any VBA/VB6 program.

Comment: Point taken....